# Pass Data from Child Array back to Parent

Tags: reactjs, react-props

It seemed pretty straight forward to pass data to a Parent useState when the child component was not in an array. But now that the child component is in an Array, it throws an error???
"sendData is not a function.

I set up a sandbox to show the problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/return-data-from-child-array-mfkl3n

Setting up a function "sendData" in the child component didn't make sense and sends an error too.
Not sure this is set up correctly?

Comment: You have to include the code as text in the question! See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `sendData` function is not passed down to the `Header` component from within `Headers`.  I forked your sandbox to show a working example... I hope that helps!

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/return-data-from-child-array-forked-6r2lc6)

**EDIT:** Added code to answer per Rabbid76's comment

```js
function Headers({ player, sendData }) {
  const items = annotations.map(({ index, title, shortDescription, end }) => {
    return (
      <Header
        headerName={title}
        shortDescription={shortDescription}
        end={end}
        index={index}
        key={index}
        // Ensure that you pass sendData to the Header component here:
        sendData={sendData}
      />
    );
  });

  return <>{items}</>;
}
```